# Remove object from std::list

Tags: c++, list

In the following situation, how can I remove the screen from the list?

```
class ScreenManager {

    list<GameScreen> screens;

    void removeScreen(GameScreen & screen) {
        //screens.remove(screen); // won't work
        //screens.erase( remove( screens.begin(), screens.end(), screen ), screens.end() );  // won't work either
    }
}
```

Comment: `remove` works. If not, then you're not telling us enough.

Comment: Give us more detail, can you supply more of the code?

Comment: Which one do you think should work? Only remove, or erase-remove? The compilation-error  is c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(1815): error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'GameScreen' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Answer (score 11):

`std::remove` (or `std::list::remove` in your case) uses the comparison operator ( `operator==`) to find/identify the object that should be remove from the container.

Since you use a user-defined type `GameScreen`, you need to provide `operator==` for your class. So, in your class you need to implement:

```
bool operator==( const GameScreen& other ) const  {
    // do whatever you need to determine whether 
    // `GameScreen` instance `other` is equal (in value) 
    // to `this` instance of `GameScreen`
}
```

Then, `screens.remove( screen);` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Use list::find to locate an iterator to the screen you actually want to remove.  Then use remove, passing it the iterator.

Comment: `remove` doesn't take an iterator, what you mean is `erase`. But `find` followed by `erase` is exactly what `remove` does, so I wonder who up-voted this.

Answer (score 2):

std::list's erase method takes an iterator you want to remove. So once you get an iterator to your screen, just pass it to screens.

In other words, you want to do `screens.erase(std::find(screens.begin(), screens.end(), screen));` This will only work if you have operator== correctly defined on your value class.

Note that if you plan to delete things a lot, you might want to use something like std::map instead of std::list (since looking up your screen in the list will be O(n).)

Comment: In fact, whenever my snippet works, remove should work too...so your issue is probably that you need to override operator==.

Comment: Could you explain what I need to do with the operator and why?

Comment: Johannes S's answer is spot on here. Essentially, remove needs to know which object in your list is the one you're looking for, and C++ doesn't give it a way to do that unless you tell it how (by overriding operator==). Another option is to have a List<GameScreen*>, "new" all of your objects, and just copy the pointers around. Then remove/find will just use pointer equality. But there are plenty of problems with that too :-)

Comment: An error: `‘CustomObject’ is not derived from ‘const _gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>’  { return *__it == _M_value; }`. I use std::for_each()